# SQL Server select with regex

Tags: sql-server, subquery

Can we use regular expression to select the item from database?

The table item is like below

```
Table column|name|
10.01.02    | a  |
100.2.03    | b  |
1021.10.04  | c  |
```

Now my problem is that i need to select the code and get the substring like below

```
Table column|name|
10.01       | a  |
100.2       | b  |
1021.10     | c  |
```

any suggestion with regular expression or substring?

Comment: Use `SUBSTRING_INDEX()`

Comment: @ypercube substring_index() not work in mssql?

Comment: You had MySQL tag before. No, I don't know of equivalent function in SQL-Server.

Comment: @ypercube sorry for my mistake,could you find any idea regarding this problem

Answer (score 3):

Sql Server doesn't really support regular expressions too well. If all you need is to pick a substring from the beginning to the second dot, combine `LEFT()` and `CHARINDEX()`, like so:

```
-- Test table with data
create table stringtest(data varchar(32), name char(1))
insert into stringtest values('10.01.02', 'a')
insert into stringtest values('100.2.03', 'b')
insert into stringtest values('1021.10.04', 'c')

select  
  data 
  , left(data, CHARINDEX('.', data, CHARINDEX('.', data, 1)+1)-1) as 'subdata'
  , name
from stringtest

-- Output:
10.01.02    10.01    a
100.2.03    100.2    b
1021.10.04  1021.10  c
```

The extraction
`left(data, CHARINDEX('.', data, CHARINDEX('.', data, 0)+1)-1) as 'subdata'`
works as follows. First, the inner `CHARINDEX('.', data, 0)` will find the 1st dot. As index is 0, it starts from the beginning of the string. +1 will point to next character after the dot  and pass that as the starting index to the outer `CHARINDEX()`. The outer will find index of the second dot. Finally, `LEFT()` will return a substring from zero to the 2nd dot.

## Edit

As per ypercube's request, let's handle some errors. First, add some data with invalid values:

```
insert into stringtest values('1021', 'd')
insert into stringtest values('1021.10', 'e')
```

And let's tune the query to include nested case statements like so,

```
select  
  data 
  , case CHARINDEX('.', data, 1) -- find first dot
    when 0 then 'No dot'
    else 
        case  CHARINDEX('.', data, CHARINDEX('.', data, 1)+1) -- find second dot
        when 0 then 'No two dots'
        else left(data, CHARINDEX('.', data, CHARINDEX('.', data, 1)+1)-1)
        end
  end
  , name
from stringtest
```

Comment: Nice but it will give error is there is a value without 2 dots.

Comment: @ypercube Well, what result do you want to have if there is only one dot? You can't expect complete answers to incomplete questions...

Comment: Of course, there are regex CLR implementations if that is actually necessary.  Such as http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/85954/Use-RegEx-in-SQL-with-CLR-Procs, etc.